# Is there any plausible mechanism through which magnetic storms can directly affect the health of people on the ground?

Tags: health

[https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A~%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions)

This study says that on average, rates of heart attack and brain stroke increased by an average factor of two(!) during geomagnetic disturbances, due to Earth's magnetism.

> It was shown statistically that **during geomagnetic disturbances the frequency of myocardial infarction and brain stroke cases increased on the average by a factor of two in comparison with quiet geomagnetic conditions**.

They offer this mechanism for this observation, and the mechanism involves magnetism:

> Our investigations show the red blood cells are very sensitive to electromagnetic forces. Most probable that geomagnetic fluctuations (frequency) acting on blood, brain, adrenals involves the adaptation system. This leads to increasing a level of catecholamines in blood responsible for activation of the clotting system, rise in aggregation and spasm in the afferent vessels of the microcirculatory network. In persons suffering from CHD, the foreground problem is the reversibility of these pathological processes.

On the other hand, USGS, a government domain website, asserts that Earth's magnetism does not affect health. The subject is on the topic of magnetic storms.

https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/does-earths-magnetic-field-affect-human-health

> "Does the Earth's magnetic field affect human health? The Earth's
> magnetic field does not directly affect human health. Humans evolved
> to live on this planet.
>
> High altitude pilots and astronauts can experience higher levels of
> radiation during magnetic storms, but the hazard is due to the
> radiation, not the magnetic field itself. **Geomagnetism can also impact
> the electrically based technology that we rely on, but it does not
> impact people themselves.**
>
> Learn more: USGS Geomagnetism Program"

It says that geomagnetism can affect electrically based technology, but it does not affect people themselves.

Health effects are not listed in their page titled "What are the hazards of magnetic storms?"

https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-hazards-magnetic-storms

Is it plausible that Earth's magnetic storms causes the rate of heart attacks to double? Is the mechanism suggested by [https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A~%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014cosp...40E1114G/abstract#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIt%20was%20shown%20statistically%20that%2Ccomparison%20with%20quiet%20geomagnetic%20conditions) in any way plausible?

Comment: What is the base rate?

Comment: The second author has been publishing on these sorts of things for a while [Breus T](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%28breus+t%5BAuthor%5D%29), unfortunately the papers are largely not available or in Russian, so hard to access for me. From abstracts, data seem sketchy at best.

Comment: Cross-posted to skeptics [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56712/does-earths-magnetism-cause-heart-attacks). Please don't clutter the network with duplicates. I suggest confirm the truth of the statement on skeptics, then come here to ask the mechanism by which it happens - *once it's been confirmed to be real*. Best to delete this here now.